# Auto confirm EULA in bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that is supposed to do some confirmation and also install software. First step of the installation process is that I am being asked to confirm the EULA and type 'yes'. Is there a way to get the 'yes' in there from the bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `yes` outputs a never-ending stream of a specified string, or `y` if unspecified.

```
$ yes | head
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
$ yes yes | ./interactive-installer  # something like this?
```

Answer (score 2):

sometimes you can use

`echo "yes"|./interactive-installer`

Answer (score 1):

[Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) may be of help there. I've never used it myself, but I understand that it allows you to specify pre-programmed responses to specific prompts.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sure this will be helpful in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Use `read`.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Confirm? (y/n):"
read confirm_val

if [[ "$confirm_val" == "y" ]] ; then
  echo "Confirmed!"
else
  echo "Not confirmed!"
fi
```

Comment: Well this script prompts the user to confirm, What I need is the opposite. The software I am trying to install from my script asks me to confirm their EULA. Now my problem is how to confirm their EULA from my script.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Confirm me ? (yes/no):"
read choice

if [ "$choice" ==  "yes" ] ; then
        echo "Confirmed!"
else
        echo "Not confirmed!"
fi
```